# Social Engineering or Broken Authentication

Tags: authentication, social-engineering

If I go to a cybercafe and use one of the shared computers, and use a social media application, which deletes session IDs when the browser is closed.

A clever person comes, who knows about the application's behaviour (that this application deletes session IDs when someone closes their browser), he asks me to move quickly and says, "Please don't close the browser, I have some urgent stuff to do." So, in a hurry I close the tab I'm using and think that I'm logged out (it is stupid, but I have seen people do that). The moment I leave, the other person starts accessing my UserID.

Regardless of my stupidity, if we see this scenario from the technical point of view, is this an example of broken authentication or social engineering or both?

Comment: You are comparing apples and oranges. If someone gets you to do something for their own aims, that's social engineering. It doesn't matter if they are also taking advantage of poor authentication or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are comparing apples and oranges. If someone gets you to do something for their own aims, that's **social engineering**. It doesn't matter if they are also taking advantage of poor authentication or not.

And this is not an incidence of broken authentication. The authentication process has happened properly. It is not supposed to do anything different in the situation other than what it has done: keep the person logged in while it was being used.

What's happened is that the browser tab hasn't ended the session. That's a browser issue, not the social media application's issue. If the application did not end the session when the tab was closed, then that's a **session management** issue, not "broken authentication".

Comment: Why is this even an _issue_? Closing a single tab does not mean the user has left so the browser has no reason to discard session id.

Comment: I was watching [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mruO75ONWy8]this and it used the term "broken authentication" for the same exact scenario. Anyways, Thanks for such clear insights!

Comment: @nobody I think you are right, maybe Schroeder can explain when did he call this a session management issue

Comment: @nobody "issue" as in "matter" or "concern", not as in "problem". For some browsers, closing the tab is equivalent to closing the browser.